# Получение координат ячейки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Создаю сапера на js 
Не работает обработчик клика
Когда пользователь нажимает на ячейку в x, y записываются координаты ячеек 
По ним определяется, есть ли мина в ячейке

Но я не вижу здесь ошибок

```
$("td").click(function () {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var x = this.target.cellIndex;
    var y = this.target.parentNode.rowIndex;
    if (game.field[x][y].isMine) {
        $(this).addClass("isMine")
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("isOpen");  
    }

});
```

Вот весь код чтобы вы понимали:

```
function setCellState() {
    this.isMine = false;
    this.isOpen = false;
    this.mineAround = 0;
  }
var game = {
  askStandartField: confirm("Стандартные настройки?"),
  width: 10,
  height: 10,
  mineCount: 9,
  standartField: function() { 
    if (!game.askStandartField) {
    game.width = prompt("Длина поля")
    game.height = prompt("Высота поля");
    game.mineCount = prompt("Кол-во мин:");
}
},  
  openCount: 0,
  field: [],
  fillField: function () {
    for (var x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {
      var row = [];
      game.field.push(row);
      for (var y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {         
        row.push(new setCellState());     
       }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < game.mineCount; i++) {     
      var xx = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.width);
      var yy = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.height);
      if (!game.field[xx][yy].isMine) {
        game.field[xx][yy].isMine = true;
      } else {
        i--;
      }
    }
  },
  drawField: function() {
  $("body").append("<table id = 'table'>");
  for (var x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {
   $("table").append("<tr>");
   for (var y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {
  $("tr:last-child").append(`<td>`);
}
}
}
};
game.standartField();
game.fillField();
game.drawField();
$("td").click(function () {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var x = this.target.cellIndex;
    var y = this.target.parentNode.rowIndex;
    if (game.field[x][y].isMine) {
        $(this).addClass("isMine")
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("isOpen");  
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("td").click(function () {
    var x = this.cellIndex;
    var y = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
    if (game.field[y][x].isMine) {
        $(this).addClass("isMine")
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("isOpen");  
    }
});
```

Comment: привет ...можно вопрос ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Привет. Конечно.

Comment: скажи плиз что здесь делает `i` ? https://jsfiddle.net/sbgkct0p/42/

Comment: @МаксимЛенский - ничего. Не используется. Можно убрать.

Comment: а каким образом можно там её использовать ? где можно почитать о этом ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Тут можно только гадать. Может там раньше был вариант, когда параметр `i` контролировал скорость анимации. Селектор тоже странный - достаточно `$("body")`.

Comment: это я часто вижу ... к примеру если открыть в opere то для тега html это не применится а только для тега body, а вот в Лисе наоборот применится для  html а для body нет ... я раньше задавал этот вопрос ...

Comment: Почему вы написали game.field[y][x], а не game.field[x][y]

Comment: Спасибо все равно!

Comment: @ЗоригтоРаднаев потому что индекс строки - первый индекс в массиве `game.field`

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Я догадывался, что это связано с "крос-браузерностью". Важно помнить, что в дерево странцы добавляются два `div.bg` элемента.

Comment: да но в webkit и в gekko по разному - в каждый вставляется по одному - по крайней мере не заметил я этого

Comment: @МаксимЛенский добавьте `alert($(".bg").length);` после вызова `prepend`