# Не могу открыть все минные ячейки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Обработчик клика:

```
$("td").click(function() {
    var x = this.cellIndex;
    var y = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
    if (game.field[x][y].isMine) {
        $(this).addClass("isMine");
        for (var x0 = 0; i < game.width; x0++) {
            for (var y0 = 0; i < game.height; y0++) {
                if (game.field[x0][y0].isMine) {
                    $('#play-table tr:nth-child(' + x0 + ') td:nth-child(' + y0 + ')').addClass("isMine");
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("isOpen");
    }
});
```

Классы в CSS прописаны правильно
Весь код:

```
function setCellState() {
    this.isMine = false;
    this.isOpen = false;
    this.mineAround = 0;
}
var game = {
    askStandartField: confirm("Стандартные настройки? 10 ячеек х 10 ячеек, 10 мин"),
    width: 10,
    height: 10,
    mineCount: 9,
    standartField: function() {
        if (!game.askStandartField) {
            game.width = prompt("Длина поля");
            game.height = prompt("Высота поля");
            game.mineCount = prompt("Кол-во мин:");
        }
    },
    openCount: 0,
    field: [],
    fillField: function() {
        for (var x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {
            var row = [];
            game.field.push(row);
            for (var y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {
                row.push(new setCellState());
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < game.mineCount; i++) {
            var xx = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.width);
            var yy = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.height);
            if (!game.field[xx][yy].isMine) {
                game.field[xx][yy].isMine = true;
            } else {
                i--;
            }
        }
    },
    drawField: function() {
        $("body").append("<table id = 'play-table'>");
        for (var x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {
            $("table").append("<tr>");
            for (var y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {
                $("tr:last-child").append(`<td>`);
            }
        }
    }
};
game.standartField();
game.fillField();
game.drawField();
$("td").click(function() {
    var x = this.cellIndex;
    var y = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
    if (game.field[x][y].isMine) {
        $(this).addClass("isMine");
        for (var x0 = 0; i < game.width; x0++) {
            for (var y0 = 0; i < game.height; y0++) {
                if (game.field[x0][y0].isMine) {
                    $('#play-table tr:nth-child(' + x0 + ') td:nth-child(' + y0 + ')').addClass("isMine");
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("isOpen");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я исправил Ваши индексы в обращении к элементам массива `game.field` в [Получение координат ячейки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843356/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8), но Вы с этим так и не разобрались.

Кроме того, ошибка, на которую Вам указали в [Нахождение ячейки в таблице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/843485/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5#comment1353902_843488), тоже не исправлена.

---

Вот Ваш подправленный код, который не выдает ошибок в консоль браузера, но явно демонстрирует ошибки логики в индексировании строк и столбцов.

```js
    function setCellState() {
        this.isMine = false;
        this.isOpen = false;
        this.mineAround = 0;
    }
    var game = {
        askStandartField: confirm("Стандартные настройки? 10 ячеек х 10 ячеек, 10 мин"),
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        mineCount: 9,
        standartField: function() {
            if (!game.askStandartField) {
                game.width = prompt("Длина поля");
                game.height = prompt("Высота поля");
                game.mineCount = prompt("Кол-во мин:");
            }
        },
        openCount: 0,
        field: [],
        fillField: function() {
            for (var x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {
                var row = [];
                game.field.push(row);
                for (var y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {
                    row.push(new setCellState());
                }
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < game.mineCount; i++) {
                var xx = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.width);
                var yy = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.height);
                if (!game.field[xx][yy].isMine) {
                    game.field[xx][yy].isMine = true;
                } else {
                    i--;
                }
            }
        },
        drawField: function() {
            $("body").append("<table id = 'play-table' border=1>");
            for (var x = 0; x < game.width; x++) {
                $("table").append("<tr>");
                for (var y = 0; y < game.height; y++) {
                    $("tr:last-child").append('<td ' + 
                      (game.field[x][y].isMine? 'class="grayMine"' : '') + 
                      '/>');
                }
            }
        }
    };
    game.standartField();
    game.fillField();
    game.drawField();
    $("td").click(function() {
        var x = this.cellIndex;
        var y = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
        if (game.field[x][y].isMine) {
            $(this).addClass("isMine");
            for (var x0 = 0; x0 < game.width; x0++) {
                for (var y0 = 0; y0 < game.height; y0++) {
                    if (game.field[x0][y0].isMine) {
                        $('#play-table tr:nth-child(' + x0 + ') td:nth-child(' + y0 + ')').addClass("isMine");
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("isOpen");
        }
    });
```

```css
td {
  width:12px;
  height:12px;
}
.grayMine {
  background-color:gray;
}
.isMine {
  background-color:red;
}
.isOpen {
  background-color:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я просто новичок в программировании и много чего не понимаю

Comment: @ЗоригтоРаднаев Пожалуйста. Вы, главное, не забывайте отмечать ответы как принятые, а мы уж Вам поможем :).